# 1993 car battery in backwards

Tags: starting, fuse

I put a battery in backwards on a1993 Toyota camery and blew the fuel injection fuse and main 100A alternator fuse. I replaced the fuses but my car won't start still. Any help?

Comment: I'm seriously sorry to hear about your mistake. But this is also perhaps where you get good motivation to start learning, too. Get a service manual for your car. Pay particular attention to the electric/electronic schematics. Get a voltmeter like this one: https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0006GD7NU Then learn how to check each bit in the car, one by one. If you can find local help through a club or meetup, take advantage. And I really am sorry it happened to you, but teaching you all this here wouldn't have worked, anyway. Best wishes.

Comment: most definately hook upto a diagnostic reader.

Comment: The service manual probably mentions 'fusible links'; pay careful attention to those, they are fuses that don't LOOK like fuses.

Answer (score 1):

Things to check:

- the wiring to the starter motor and alternator out, you may have done some damage there.
- the battery itself, test with a voltmeter to see what state it is in and/or try a known good battery in the car
- fuse(s) to the engine electronics